# Why doesn't abide show the error message for the email input?

Tags: zurb-foundation, abide

I built a simple contact form using foundation and its abide plugin. It's basically working, except one thing: The validation for the email input field.

- If I submit the form without entering any data, abide shows both validation error messages correctly.
- If I enter just input into the message `textarea` and leave the email `input` blank, then abide prevents submitting the form, but it doesn't show the error message. It just marks the email `input` as invalid.
- If I enter a valid email address and leave the message `textarea` blank, then abide shows both validation error messages although the email address is correct.

You can check it on jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/cacucunama

Minimal running example (same as jsbin):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>ZURB Foundation Abide form validation error</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-abide novalidate id="footer-contact-form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label">N</span>
            <input name="user[name]" value="" type="text" id="footer-contact-form--name" class="input-group-field"
                placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label">@</span>
            <input name="user[email]" value="" type="email" id="footer-contact-form--email" class="input-group-field"
                placeholder="Email address*" required pattern="email">
        </div>
        <label class="form-error" data-form-error-for="footer-contact-form--email">Valid email required.</label>
        <textarea name="user[message]" id="footer-contact-form--message" placeholder="Message*" rows="3"
            required=""></textarea>
        <label class="form-error" data-form-error-for="footer-contact-form--message">A message is required.</label>
        <button value="" type="submit" class="button expanded">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not crosspost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered at https://foundation.discourse.group/t/abide-doesnt-show-the-correct-validation-error-message/2276/10 you forgot to wrap the label + input pars in the part with the email input and message textarea.

https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/dyYpjYZ

It works with the following code:

```html
<form action="#" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-abide novalidate id="footer-contact-form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label">N</span>
            <input name="user[name]" value="" type="text" id="footer-contact-form--name" class="input-group-field"
                placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
              <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-label">@</span>
                  <input name="user[email]" value="" type="email" id="footer-contact-form--email" class="input-group-field"
                      placeholder="Email address*" required pattern="email">
              </div>
              <label class="form-error" data-form-error-for="footer-contact-form--email">Valid email required.</label>
        </div>
        <div>
              <textarea name="user[message]" id="footer-contact-form--message" placeholder="Message*" rows="3"
                  required=""></textarea>
              <label class="form-error" data-form-error-for="footer-contact-form--message">A message is required.</label>
        </div>
        <button value="" type="submit" class="button expanded">Send</button>
    </form>
```